# ValueError Expected singleton: res.partner(3, 1, 5) sign up?

Tags: odoo

Not sure why I am facing this error on my site. I have tried all methods to fix it.

Error is being thrown here :

> return super(res_users, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context) this
>   line file is odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py line 385.

from here error is being thrown

Comment: Give us more info please. That error happens due to the method `ensure_one`. This method checks that a recordset brings exactly one record, if it brings none or more than one, gives the error you are receiving. In your case, any part of the code expects to receive one partner, and it's receiving three (the partners with ID 1, 3 and 5).

Comment: I don't think this is answerable in its current form. A good rule of thumb on Stack Overflow is that if your question is just one or two sentences long, it cannot contain enough detail to be answered. See other questions here - they contain several paragraphs, and show code and configuration.

Comment: thank you for prompt response. 

This is what I have : 
return super(res_users, self).copy(cr, uid, id, default, context) this line file is odoo/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py line 385.
from here error is being thrown

Comment: which type of code you do? and this error is occurred.

Comment: Sorry Friends, I fixed it out of my own : hard coded the required filed for respective model in a controlled condition. It worked for our launch :)